# Can I use the .each Method to Solve this sum problem?

Tags: ruby, sum, each

still new to Ruby. Noob question, please bear with me. And thank you ahead of time.
I love the .each method over something like the while loop. The while loop is confusing for me. I love the neatness of the .each method. Can I use the .each method to solve this question below? I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out if I can use this style loop.

Thank you for your help!

```
 def sum_nums(max)



puts sum_nums(4) # => 10, because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
puts sum_nums(5) # => 15
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but if you need to calculate arithmetic progression you can use `(1..5).reduce(:+)`

Comment: @AndreiKovrov Or `(1..5).sum` with newer Rubies.

Comment: Further to @mu's comment, `(1..5).sum` computes the sum of an arithmetic series from the endpoints of the range: `5*(1+5)/2 #=> 15`.

Comment: ...and from the size of the range (the first '5' in my example).

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you can use the .each method to solve this question. Pulling hairs out is not the way however. Try initializing a variable to 0 outside the each- block, and add all values in the block to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

So to answer the OP (and borrowing shamelessly from all the other answers)

```rb
def sum_nums(n)
  (1..n).sum
end

puts sum_nums(5)
# => 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options of how to sum all numbers from 1 to n in Ruby:

```rb
1.upto(4).reduce(:+) # => 10
1.upto(5).reduce(:+) # => 15

(1..4).reduce(:+) # => 10
(1..5).reduce(:+) # => 15

# could use `each`, but it is doing nothing here.
(1..4).each.reduce(:+) # => 10
(1..5).each.reduce(:+) # => 15

# same thing with `each`, but keeping track of the sum manually
sum = 0
(1..4).each do |i|
  sum += i
end
# i => 10
```

Basically you get an Enumerable (iterator/collection abstraction) that spans over the things you would like enumerate. In our case we would like to go from 1 to 4. We can get an Enumerable for that either by calling `Integer#upto` method (like so: `1.upto(4)`, or by using Range (like so `(1..4)`). Then we can use any Enumerable methods on the collection/iterator.

`Enumerable#each` simply calls a block for every element (and when called without a block, essentially does nothing, just returns the same Enumerable), but Enumerable also has built-in functions for finding minimum, maximum, reducing (in our case we're doing the sum, so `reduce` fits), etc. For more detailed information see docs for Enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

An example way that comes into my mind.

```
def sum_nums(max)
  sum = 0
  array = Array.new(max) { |i| (i + 1) }
  array.each { |element| sum += element }
  puts sum
end

sum_nums(4) # => 10
sum_nums(5) # => 15
```